# emacs でジャンプ前の位置に戻りたい

Tags: emacs

emacs で作業をしていると、たとえば <kbd>C-v</kbd>, <kbd>M-v</kbd>などで、意図せずスクロールして、ポイントの位置がずれてしまうことがあります。このような場合に、元のポイントまでカーソルを戻したいと考えました。これを実現する方法などありますか？

#### 知っていること

- <kbd>C-SPC</kbd><kbd>C-SPC</kbd> でマークをアクティベート・ディアクティベートしたのちに、 <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-SPC</kbd> でその場所まで戻ることができる。 (mark ring から pop する)
- しかし、これだとカーソルを動かす前にその位置をマークしておく必要があり、「つい」移動してしまった直後だとこの方法は活用できない。

Comment: お探しの機能は[point-undo.el](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/rubikitch/20081230/pointundo)でしょうか。

Comment: @payaneco その通りの様子です。よろしければ、回答いただければ、承認できるのですが。。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメント欄から転記します。
[point-undo.el](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/rubikitch/20081230/pointundo)を用いることでカーソル位置の履歴をたどって移動できるようです。